# Extend CollectionType add indexOutOfRange function

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm trying to add a function that tells me if an index is out of range in an array.

the startIndex and endIndex of CollectionType seem to be generic, so I'm trying to restrict the extension only when the index type is Int. 
This code does not compile:

```
extension CollectionType where Index.Type is Int {
    public func psoIndexOutOfRange(index: Index.Type) -> Bool{
        return index < self.startIndex || index > self.endIndex
    }
}
```

Is it possible? and what would be the correct way to add this.

Comment: "psoIndexOutOfRange" ? Is that some kind of [Hungarian Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I think this would be better as an extension to `Range`, rather than to `CollectionType`:

```
extension Range where T: Comparable {
    func contains(element: Generator.Element) -> Bool {
        return element >= startIndex && element < endIndex
    }
}
```

which you could call like so (`indices` returns the range from the collection’s start to end index):

```
[1,2,3].indices.contains(2)
```

Note, `CollectionType` (which `Range` conforms to) already has a `contains` method – but done via linear search.  This overloads `contains` for ranges specifically to do it in constant time.

Also, if you're doing this in order to combine it with a subscript fetch, consider adding an optional fetch to make things easier:

```
extension CollectionType where Index: Comparable {
    subscript(safe idx: Index) -> Generator.Element? {
        guard indices.contains(idx) else { return nil }
        return self[idx]
    }
}

let a = [1,2,3]
a[safe: 4]  // nil
```

Comment: This is great, one question though, why check element < endIndex instead as element <= endIndex. Is it not the endIndex the last index ?

Comment: No - endIndex is a "sentinel value" a fake value the represents you've gone past the last valid index. So with an array `[1,2,3]`, `endIndex` will be 3.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
extension CollectionType where Index: Comparable {
    public func psoIndexOutOfRange(index: Index) -> Bool{
        return index < self.startIndex || index >= self.endIndex
    }
}
```

As @MartinR suggested, it's more general if you use `Comparable` instead of constraining `Index` to be of type `Int`.